# Issue with node version

Tags: 22.04, nodejs

I'm trying to run the following command in a Angular project "npm run ng", but I'm getting a warning that my Node.js version is incorrect.

> Node.js version v10.23.0 detected.
> The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10.
> Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

The issue is that I don't even have version 10.23 installed.

> nvm ls
> ->     v16.19.0
> default -> 16.19.0 (-> v16.19.0)
> iojs -> N/A (default)
> unstable -> N/A (default)
> node -> stable (-> v16.19.0) (default)
> stable -> 16.19 (-> v16.19.0) (default)
> lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> N/A)
> lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
> lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
> lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
> lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
> lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
> lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
> lts/gallium -> v16.20.0 (-> N/A)
> lts/hydrogen -> v18.16.0 (-> N/A)

> node -v v16.19.0
> npm -v 9.7.1

Any ideas what is happening here ?

Comment: What is the output when you run `which npm`?